# for field recording(nature/wildlife) use Mono or Stereo XRL- NGT2 into Tascam DR-100mkii?

Tags: field-recording, stereo, mono

Want to start off on the right foot, i am a beginner when it comes to field recording, more interested in environmental, natural, wildlife sounds as well as construction sites, trains, busy street corners--- Is mono best for dialogue/voice/vocals and stereo best for outdoors/etc. ?

I have a Rode NGT-2 and a Tascam DR-100mkii, do I record in mono or stereo when using the Rode mic into the Tascam?

thank you very much,
JC

Answer (score 1):

First off, you want stereo for "spot" recordings. For that you need at least 2 microphones, so unfortunately your Rode mic does you no good by itself for that application.

However, your Tascam has four built in mics and can record in stereo by itself. Just use that! Keep the Rode for vocals, spoken word, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Always stereo for atmos and ambient sounds. It makes no sense to record mono, unless it's fill sound. Today surround is also popular. And yes mono for dialogue. If it's for the purpose of putting together a library you can sell, no one will want mono recordings.

You can only record mono with the ntg 2 anyway. You would need a stereo mic for stereo recording.

Comment: Thank you! It's a bummer about the ntg-2 only being mono-- I was misinformed-- I researched and believed I could use it outdoors to focus on a single bird call, etc. things like that?  any suggestions for an affordable, small budget, stereo mic? Thanks again JC

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand. You can use it on individual sounds such as bird calls. It all depends on use. Is it for post production? You need a stereo mic for ambience. Eg to over -lay over an entire scene. Mono is fine foe spot sounds etc.

Comment: This answer may have been better as a comment responding to the comment below. I was very confused at first haha.